# Angular routing and importing components from a library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have set up a simple skeleton representing my application here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e68rbx

The app module loads and hands off to a framework module which hosts the main pages in my app.

To demonstrate the problem I have put 1 of my component library buttons in each of the `framework` and `test-page` components but no matter what I try I cannot get the button in the `test-page` to render as a button from my library.

If I import the `ButtonModule` in the `app.module.ts` then neither button is rendered correctly.

If I import the `ButtonModule` in the `framework.module.ts` then the button in the `framework` page is rendered correctly, but the button in the `test-page` is not.

What is the correct way to get a library module working throughout an Angular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TestPageComponent` needs to be declared anywhere. So if you don't wanna do it in the `App.Module.ts` so you need to to this in the `Framework.Module`.  With lazy loading it helps for better performance. So change your `framework.module.ts` like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FrameworkComponent } from './framework.component';
import { FrameworkRoutingModule } from './framework.routing.module';
import { ButtonModule } from 'jon-component';
import { TestPageComponent } from '../components/test-page/test-page.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [FrameworkComponent, TestPageComponent],
  imports: [FrameworkRoutingModule, CommonModule, ButtonModule],
  exports: [FrameworkComponent, RouterModule],
})
export class FrameworkModule {}
```

You see the **TestPageComponent** in the line `declarations: [FrameworkComponent, TestPageComponent],` does the trick.

[image]

Comment: Oh man. I spent so long debugging the library and associated imports that i completely forgot about the structure of the application components. Many, many thanks.